# Story about a typewriting girl with telekinesis powers (before the 90s)

Tags: story-identification, novel, telekinesis

I'm asking for someone else, who read a book in the nineties (could have been written in the '80s or even '70s) about a girl in a typewriting school discovering her supernatural powers, associated with anger. Thunderstorms are involved.

It's not Carrie nor Matilda.

It may be a book for teenagers. It was read in French, but my friend thinks it was certainly a translation from English.

Comment: Sounds like the same search is happening here (might be your friend actually!) - https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/22560273-ya-sci-fi-fantasy-horror-young-girl-discovering-she-gradually-manif